# WPF locbaml-ed application and runtime language switch?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization, locbaml

i wonder if there is a simple solution to change language of a wpf application during runtime. i used locbaml to globalize all the resources. Setting the Current Thread's UICulture in the App-constructor works fine, but when i try to chang it a little bit later, i doesn't reflect the changes anymore.
This was actually quite easy with winforms, but i have no clue how to solve the same problem with wpf.
any ideas?
regards
j.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Once you load an assembly and it is bound to your application, you can not change classes in mid-work. You could create a bootstrapper assembly that loads the current language and when you change the language you close and re-open your application automatically, but I doubt that's what you want or need.

What I did on one of my projects was create a globalized application framework using converters, etc. You can see some of the problems I ran into [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/tags/WPF/default.aspx) and especially [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/okloeten/archive/2007/12/12/5443446.aspx) which shows how it looked. HTH if you decide to go the same way as I did.